# What is the list of things needed for Vedic marriage?

Tags: marriage

There are descriptions of several marriages in Hindu scriptures such as marriages of Sita Rama, Parvati parameswara etc.,

Is there any mention on the complete or partial list of the *necessary* things needed for marriage? The things (not persons) I'm referring are only things used during the marriage event(ritual).

Comment: i think we need an actual purohit / bruhaspati to visit this site to answer this question.

Comment: @ram do you mean that there is no mention in scriptures?

Comment: you'll def. find mantras, but i doubt any online scripture lists the actual items needed